Android CameraX Video Capture: ERROR_NO_VALID_DATA when starting recording
I'm trying to implement video recording in my Android app using CameraX. The app displays the camera preview correctly, but when I try to start recording, I get the following
error:Sending VideoRecordEvent Finalize [error: ERROR_NO_VALID_DATA]
Dependencies in build.gradle:
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-rc01")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-rc01")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-rc01")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.0-rc01")

My related function:
   private fun initializeVideoCapture() {
        val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
            .setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.HIGHEST))
            .build()
        videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun startRecording() {
        val videoCapture = this.videoCapture ?: return

        val videoFile = File(
            outputDirectory,
            "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4"
        )

        val outputOptions = FileOutputOptions.Builder(videoFile).build()
        recording = videoCapture.output
            .prepareRecording(this, outputOptions)
            .withAudioEnabled()
            .start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)) { recordEvent ->
                when (recordEvent) {
                    is VideoRecordEvent.Start -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    is VideoRecordEvent.Finalize -> {
                        if (recordEvent.hasError()) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording succeeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        recording?.close()
                        recording = null
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    private fun stopRecording() {
        recording?.stop()
        recording = null
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private fun createOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
        }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

I have ensured that the necessary permissions (CAMERA, RECORD_AUDIO) are requested and granted. The app correctly initializes the camera and displays the preview, but fails when attempting to start video recording.
What could be causing the ERROR_NO_VALID_DATA error, and how can I resolve it to successfully record and save videos?
